# Python scraping urls category

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Hello I'm starting now in programming and I'm having some problems with Scraping, I'm trying to get all the links in a category with several names, but I'm not getting isolate the cells because there are many with the same name, could someone help me? I will put the picture of my code and the url I want to get.

`

```html
url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/index.html'
reqs = requests.get(url)
if reqs.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
    ul = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'nav nav-list'})
    for cells in ul:
        a = cells.find('a')
        link = a['href']
        #print(link)
        [print(str(lis) + '\n\n') for lis in link]
```

=== LINK IMAGE ===

I need to retrieve all urls in (li)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.  I have commented the code to explain what I've done and why.  You can obviously write this in fewer lines but this explains a little easier.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/index.html'
reqs = requests.get(url)
if reqs.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

    # use multiple class selector list
    sidebar = soup.find('ul', {"class": ["nav", "nav-list"]})

    # find all the list tags within the ol
    li = sidebar.find_all('li')

    for item in li:
        # iterate through results to find a link
        link = item.find('a', href=True)
        # if there is a link print it
        if link is not None:
            print(link['href'])
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by going straight to the links:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/index.html'
reqs = requests.get(url)
if reqs.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
    ul = soup.find_all('a')
    for cells in ul:
        print(cells['href'])
```